# How to use same StoryBoard for Multiple ViewConntrollers in ios swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have almost 10 screens with same StoryBoard. everyTime I am coping and pasting storyBoard. I think this is not the right way. could anyone help me for better solution?

Comment: what you mean with "I am coping and pasting storyBoard" ?

Comment: Create a base class for them eg.`BaseViewController` and let other 10 screen subclass of `BaseViewController`

Comment: In some cases it's good to have different storyboards for different places in your application. For example you can group all the login / register viewControllers in 1 storyboard, and all the payment steps in another. What i think you are looking for in your question is the usage of segues. However, segues are much more advanced than doing it programmatically when it comes to sending data back and forth.

Comment: what is the reason for creating different storyboards for each view controllers you can have all view controllers in single storyboard itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many cases, apps can (and should) use a single storyboard file. The are certainly exceptions for large apps that you want to break into more modular sections. But initially, I would start with a single storyboard.

When you have the storyboard open in Xcode and want to create a new view controller, just drag the "View Controller" item from the object library next to an existing view controller. You can then add segues from one view controller to the other. Finally, be sure that you set the custom class for your new view controller in the inspection panel.

[image: Interface builder in Xcode]

Comment: it would a nightmare to maintain a single storyboard for the whole app, especially when working as a team: merging, conflicts, xcode performance, etc